# npm doesn't work on internal terminal in linux mint (ubuntu based OS)

Tags: node.js, npm

when i write this command in vs code internal terminal : npm --version
it says:

```
npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
npm WARN config     [cacache](http://npm.im/cacache).
9.6.1npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
npm WARN config     [cacache](http://npm.im/cacache).
9.6.1,
```

it was saying command not found in internal vscode terminal.I updated node and npm with nvm. Now i have this error in every npm command. I'm using linux mint

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that when node and npm was updated with nvm that the PATH environement didn't get updated to inlcude where the npm excutable was installed.

To add the correct path variable, here's how: $HOME is the home directory of the current user
$NVM_DIR is the environment variable used by NVM
`export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" export PATH="$PATH:$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin"`

with this command, it will use the path of the current version of Node.js installed by nvm to the path.

It should make npm --version work again.